# Correct PHP Syntax for custom WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, loops

I am trying to insert a sorting option into my wordpress site. I already have it working, but need help using it with the wordpress loop correctly. Currently, I have:

**On a page, there are options to sort alphabetically or chronologically:**

```
<a href="?sort=date">Newest</a>
<a href="?sort=title">Alphabetical</a>
```

**Sorting Code starts here, placed above the loop:**

```
<?php $sort= $_GET['sort']; 
    if($sort == "title") { $order= "'orderby'=>'title','order'=>ASC'"; } 
    elseif($sort == "date") { $order= "'orderby'=>'date'"; } 
    else{ $order= "'orderby'=>'date','order'=>'DESC'"; } 
?>
```

*note: I am pretty sure the problem lies above in the variable $order*

**Wordpress Loop Using Variable `$order` as an argument**

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( $order, 'post_type' => 'films', 'post_parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    Wordpress loop stuff here

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The loop displays items correctly, but the sorting links are not working. This code works very well with query_posts but I am trying to get this to work for WP_Query (above). Any ideas here?

**UPDATE**: This technique works great using query_posts like below (but I still need it working for WP_Query):

```
<?php $sort= $_GET['sort']; 
    if($sort == "title") { $order= "&orderby=title&order=ASC"; } 
    elseif($sort == "date") { $order= "&orderby=date"; } 
    else{ $order= "&orderby=date&order=DESC"; } 
?>

<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string . $order); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       Wordpress Stuff Here
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`WP_Query` expects associative array of parameters (`array('param' => 'value')`), whereas query_posts accepts only "query strings" (`"param=value&param=value"`). You are mixing both options, that's why it doesn't work. You need to change `$order` variable to be array instead of string, for example: `$order = array('orderby' => 'title', 'order' => ASC');`.</strike>

Answer above is not complete and may be misleading. `WP_Query` docs are here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query . This class accepts boths styles, but they must be somewhat different formed. I don't know how exactly to do this, because it is not written in class docs, but you better use arrays, so:

```
if($sort == "title") { $order = array('orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'); } 
elseif($sort == "date") { $order= array('orderby' => 'date'); } 
else{ $order= array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'); }
```

FYI to convert between both types use functions `parse_str()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php and `http_build_query()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php .

Comment: Ok, I changed the variables into arrays instead of strings. Now I need to pass the array $order to the WP_Query. Using $order is not working. How would I use parse_str() in order for it to pass the array?

Comment: Use `$loop = new WP_Query(array_merge($order, array('post_type' => 'films', 'post_parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1)))`.

Comment: that is exactly as I have it, I just need help passing it to the loop

Comment: Use the line from the comment above.

Comment: No problem, that's my job and I appreciate help given to me as much as i help others. :)