# Storing complex string in PHP Variable

Tags: php, variables

Is it possible to store soemthing like this in a php string:

```
$variable = "'orderby'=>'title','order'=>ASC'"
```

I want to use it in a wordpress loop, but am unsure if I can store multiple arguments in a single variable as a string. For example, I do not want the variable to store multiple arguments, but rather the entire quoted text as a string.

Comment: WordPress itself stores such data as JSON so apart from the fact that Trey's answer is good, you shouldn't use `serialize()` if you're going to store that data in database.

Comment: I see...I am trying to solve the problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170480/correct-php-syntax-for-custom-wp-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON:

```
// $json contains {'orderby':'title','order':'ASC'}
$json = json_encode(array('orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'));
```

Comment: how would I use JSON in the context of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170480/correct-php-syntax-for-custom-wp-loop

Comment: I've answered that question, please look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to create an array or object and serialize it...:

```
$variable = array('orderby'=>'title','order'=>'ASC');
$string=serialize($variable);
```

in response to your question about using it in the loop...

```
$args=array( 'post_type' => 'films', 'post_parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$more=unserialize($variable);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args+$more );
```

Json is a faster conversion format as others are trying to point out, and if you're only using this for simple arrays it may be the better solution. Serialize offers some very interesting features for Objects

Comment: how is the variable $string defined?

Comment: it's a mysql safe string that defines an array... you can use `unserialize($string)` to return it to an array

Comment: if I store them as an array, could I use the variable in the loop like so:   <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'films', 'post_parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1, serialize($variable); ) ); ?>