# Passing Array into Wordpress Loop

Tags: arrays, wordpress, variables, loops

I am trying to store different values into an array based on a number of conditions like so:

```
<?php $sort= $_GET['sort']; 

     if($sort == "title") { $args = array('orderby'=>'title','order'=>'ASC'); } 
     elseif($sort == "date") { $args = array('orderby'=>'date'); } 
     else{ $args = array('orderby'=>'date','order'=>'DESC'); } 
?>
```

And then I am trying to insert the variable `$args` into the wordpress loop using WP_Query like so:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( $args, 'post_type' => 'films', 'post_parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    wordpress loop stuff, and the end while, end if
```

This is not working correctly. Am I passing the array into the wordpress loop incorrectly?

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions when there are answer to previous ones you didn't try.

Comment: Apologies...Just keep finding ways to write it better.

Comment: Correct answer is here, thanks Tomasz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170480/correct-php-syntax-for-custom-wp-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passing an array, $args, into another array. WP_Query can't understand the double nested array.

Why don't you just set a variable for the value you want assigned to the orderby and order parameters based on the result of the conditionals.

```
if ( $sort == 'title' ) {
   $orderby = 'title';
   $order = 'ASC';
} esleif ( // ....etc
```

Then in your query array:

```
  'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, etc..
```